# Saving a canvas in Android does not work every time

Tags: android, canvas, surfaceview

I'm having this code:

```
public void saveimage() {
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(colorGFX.getWidth(),
            colorGFX.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
    canvas = colorGFX.canvas;
    canvas.setBitmap(bitmap);
    saveBitmap(bitmap);
}
```

colorGFX object extends a SurfaceView.

saveBitmap actually writes the image on the file.

The problem is that most of the times a WHITE image is saved, other times the correct image is saved.

Did I missed something, or why does the image saves only let's say 1/5 of the times?

Comment: If you replace 3 lines Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);    canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);    canvas = colorGFX.canvas; by only 1 line: Canvas canvas = colorGFX.canvas; what happens?

Comment: An empty (black) image is saved then.

Comment: And if you add colorGFX.invalidate(); just before canvas.setBitmap(bitmap); what do you get?

Comment: Nothing happens. Same as before, sometimes it saves the images but most of the times it save a white empty image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(colorGFX.getWidth(),
            colorGFX.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
canvas.drawBitmap(colorGFX.bitmap, 0f, 0f, null);
canvas.drawBitmap(colorGFX.pictureBitmap, 0f, 0f, null);
saveBitmap(bitmap);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public void saveimage() {
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(colorGFX.getWidth(),
            colorGFX.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    colorGFX.draw(new Canvas(bitmap))
    saveBitmap(bitmap);
}
```

Comment: Same empty image (black) is saved.

Comment: In that case, you need to inspect your colorGFX object/view. How do you use it? How is it layed out? Can you provide the code source of colorGFX?

Comment: Seen anything unusual?

Comment: @CristianG: I can not test your code, it crashes when I touch the creen. I suspect the thread in your view blocks your canvas to be available when you call it to saveBitmap.